# Weather information not showing up on lock screen like before

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, lock-screens, weather

I have a Samsung Galaxy S5 phone, in my previous version of Android (presumably KitKat), I configured it to show basic weather information on the lock screen for that day (typically temperature and overall conditions outside). This setting is in Settings > Lock Screen > Additional Info > check "Weather" box to enable.

Since I upgraded to Lollipop, the setting is still there, but even when I enable it the weather info no longer shows up on the lock screen. Pedometer is working, all the other lock screen settings seem to be working. Did they remove this one feature in Lollipop? Because honestly I found it really handy so I didn't have to unlock my phone just to view the current temperature.

Does anyone know if this is a bug or was it removed and they forgot to remove the actual option to display it?

Comment: @Huey - Samsung's baked-in weather and pedometer widgets should still appear on the lockscreen even under Lollipop if the settings are configured as indicated.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the pedometer widget, which I solved by toggling the **Additional information** and **Pedometer** settings on and off and rebooting.

Also note that the weather and pedometer widgets only display if there are no other notifications showing on the lock screen.

Comment: Your note about no other notifications fixes it for me. What a horrible "feature". My owner message was what number to call if the phone is found, but this pretty much guarantees it will never be seen

Answer (score 1):

Hey I had the same problem. Slide the drop down menu from top. Turn on 'location'. Click agree when this shows up -- Improve location accuracy? --

Then go to the clock-weather app (should be on your homescreen). Click the '+' button on top right corner. DONOT type and search for your location instead press the 'location icon' and let your phone automatically locate you. SELECT whatever shows up, refresh and update weather and then lock your screen. It should show up now.
(:

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem and Samsung Philippines said that the new Lollipop-OS removed the weather feature in lock screen.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Samsung Galaxy A5 and all of a sudden my weather wiget stopped updating and couldn't find my location. The time on the wiget works fine but not the weather and it no longer shows my location. I checked my weather feature in lock screen and it was turned on but it still would not find my location. I had to turn the weather feature in lock screen to OFF and then it works again and found my location immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn the lock screen display features like the Camera shortcut, Weather and Pedometer on or off by going to the following directory.
1.SETTINGS 
2.Tap On GENERAL
3.Scroll down and tap on Accessories
4.Scroll down and tap on "Select items to display"
5.And here you are. Feel free to check or uncheck the features of your choice to show on your android 5.0 lock screen.
Note: You may have to restart your device for the changes to take place.

Answer (score 0):

[phenry's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/105574/44325) mentioned that you couldn't run the weather and pedometer at the same time. I was trying to run it with the news ticker. I found out that I could run both if I deleted the clock from the clock screen. So, maybe two but not three.

Answer (score 0):

FYI I've run weather and pedometer health apps same time for years.  No issues.

I've a gs3,  gs4,  gs5, updated to android 5 and 6 versions noticed that only clock showed no weather information Iin weather widget.   Infact no weather, no colour photo ot animation, just a clock left side. Kept deleting and re adding weather clock 4x2 widget,  the Samsung default one.  Nothing still same result.

Went to
Settings /Application Manager / Change System Settings

Seems I'd somehow lost the ability to turn my "Systems Settings" On Off toggle for apps.   Unified Daemon and others appeared greyed out or off and couldn't be turned back on.

I remembered that I'd gone crazy restricting tons of apps to get better battery life.

************* verified solution below  ************

Solution :  after fearing that " Reset to defaults" in menu would ruin my settings,  trying all of the above and downloading the stock 4.4.01 apk and unifiedaemon that came with it.  I was warned by installed that I'd be overwriting a newer one with older.   I canceled that asap.

After 3 hours decided to hit the reset all to default in the Change System Settings under the menu key.

Goto 
application manager
change system settings " ( from menu drop down) then when next screen appears ( hit menu key ) select 
"reset app preferences "

That's it enjoy accuweather,
 no reboot or restart required 
did 4 phones.

I've got to go back in and restrict apps that I don't want to control my system.  But I won't touch unifiedDaemon 100%

Whose gonna point us to the true apk for Samsung accuweather apk from Gs6,  Gs7  ???  Not some cloned look alike app that requires a 3rd party widget editing and downloading app.  I don't want unnecessary apps.

Only want the true  original APK made for galaxy S phones by Samsung and accuweather.  I've got the Gs7  phones,  a how to pull from there to gs5 would be appreciated.   I'll share it too.