# How to show weather info on lock screen?

Tags: lock-screens, 6.0-marshmallow, samsung-galaxy-s-6, weather

I updated my Galaxy S6 to Android 6.0.1  yesterday. I can't seem to get the weather info to show on my lock screen. I have a fingerprint lock screen. I did get Spotify to show on the lock screen.

I have tried:

- Settings → Applications → Weather → Weather Notifications = On
- Settings → Notifications → Advanced → Weather → Set As Priority = On
- Settings → Notifications → Advanced → Weather → Previews in Pop-ups = On
- Settings → Notifications → Advanced → Weather → Hide On Lock Screen = Off
- Settings → Notifications → Advanced → Weather → Hide Content On Lock Screen = Off

I have read the posts:

- [Show messages on lock screen](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/45069/show-messages-on-lock-screen)
- [Weather information not showing up on lock screen like before](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/105212/weather-information-not-showing-up-on-lock-screen-like-before)

Comment: Do you mean show weather app as a shortcut or show weather info on lock screen?

Comment: Weather info.  Example: "Kansas City 68* Sunny".  Something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that in the Yahoo weather app, you can turn on a persistent notification. It will be showing up on your lockscreen.

Comment: Seems like that's the only answer so far.  Thanks!